# Finding square root of a 32 bit unsigned number

Tags: verilog

How to find out square root of a 32-bit unsigned fixed point number in verilog? Input is 32 bit positive integer.  The output should be represented in 16.16 format (16 integer and 16 fractional bits). I am using Zynq board from xilinx.

Comment: You mean the algorithm? I suggest you to google it.

Comment: I googled it but without finding division how to do it? I didn't find any algorithm without division.

Comment: I'll give you a magical keyword: "CORDIC".

Comment: I know about this...But is there any other simple way?

Comment: Can't you do Newton-Raphson without division, or am I misremembering? There's also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: @pjc50 I might be wrong, but I think it is not well-suited for a non-floating point calculation

Comment: NR needs division

Comment: If division is required, then implement a divider.

Comment: How to implement division in verilog? I am new to verilog

Comment: http://www.ijcee.org/papers/767-ET030.pdf

Comment: There is more than one way to do this. You should tell us what you want to optimize for. Do you need high throughput, low delay, few gates? Do you have hardware multipliers available? Does it need to be bit accurate down to the LSB?

Comment: @bibo, thats your tradeoff, FPGA's aren't good for doing everthing. SQRTs are hard to implement. There are other ways of doing this thing, a lot of times you can do away with it if you change your dsp or control loop. Get creative. If you need a slow one then depending on the FPGA you can put a processor on it.

Comment: @bibo: N-R does *NOT* require division. The "trick" is to calculate \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\$ using N-R, which requires only multiplication and shifting, and then do one more multiplication \$x\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\$ to get \$\sqrt{x}\$. If you have a good starting point (e.g., a ROM lookup table), it converges rapidly, roughly doubling the number of accurate bits on each iteration. If you start with an 8-bit value from a ROM, you can get 56 accurate bits in 3-4 iterations. You can also implement division by first doing inversion (\$\frac{1}{x}\$) the same way.

Comment: @DaveTweed I can use this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root for finding 1/root x.

Answer (score 5):

One simple approach is interval bisection.

Here is some pseudocode. I assume that division by 2 rounds towards zero. The final result will also be rounded towards zero. I assume that both input and output are in 16.16 fixed point (re-reading your quesiton I notice that you specified the decimal point location for the output but not for the input)

```
low = 0.0
high = 256.0
in = (value you want to square root)
epsilon = (smallest value you can represent)
do {
  mid = (high + low) / 2 
  multresult = (mid * mid)
  if (multresult <= in) low = mid
  if (multreslut >= in) high = mid
} while ((high - low) > epsilon)
result = low
```

There are two ways this can terminate. Either it finds the exact answer or the interval is reduced to epsilon.

It should be easy enough to implement this as a verilog state machine.

- Division by 2 is just a bit shift.
- Fixed point multiplication is easy enough. Just do an integer multiply followed by moving bits arround. Just make sure your multiplier is wide enough that things don't overflow.
- Fixed point addition, subtraction and comparision are the same as integer addition subtraction and comparision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.....How to do Fixed point multiplication in verilog? If you can give one example it will be helpful...Also what would be the high value if it's a 32 bit input...